# Score Lead Account based on email opens / clicks from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce1-app, automationstudio

**Overview**

We have some custom 'scoring' fields on leads, accounts.  The actual 'score' comes from a custom settings field and users get a score based on opens, clicks, etc and campaign; some campaigns get higher score than others.

I plan to use a apex class to update the score field on the lead, account.

**Question**

To get the clicks, opens from MC to SF, I'm thinking of running a batch job (apex) that can pick a file? from MC; the MC file would inclde subscriber id, opens, clicks.

In MC, use Automation Studio to provide the file of opens, clicks.

Is this the best approach to 1) Using Automation Studio get the open, clicks  info and 2) apex job to process the Automation Studio file

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I believe you could use just Automation Studio to do this for you, there's little to no need to have an Apex job doing anything on top with it if you use case is just updating Sales Cloud records.

With Automation Studio you can utilize Script Activity to run a [**mixture of SSJS and AMPScript**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_useSSJSAMPscript.htm) to make outbound calls to Sales Cloud to update the records and/or scoring. Although unless you know (or are willing to learn) SSJS and AMPScript, you can do this with Apex as well.

Overall you would be using Automation Studio to build the SQL queries about the Data Views, combining the result Data Extensions to a final target one and then using Script Activity to do the actions required.

Comment: Thanks Rain!  That's exactly what I was thinking; Automation Studio